# Change fragment from spinner in a top fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I've an app with a tab view, which has 2 tab. Tab 2 contains a spinner that has a drop-down function. The spinner includes Prova 1, 2, etc. Clicking on each item will open a fragment below. Clicking on the Prova 1, will take me to a page that show some information, but it doesn't work.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToRGr.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDqrA.png)

[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRDfY.png)

FragmentTop.java

```
public class FragmentTop extends Fragment { //implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private Spinner spinner;
    private String[] items;
    private FragmentProva1 fragmentProva1;

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public FragmentTop() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentTop newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentTop fragment = new FragmentTop();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_Top, container, false);
        items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Top);
        fragmentProva1 = new FragmentProva1();
        spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTop);
        initSpinner();

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    private void initSpinner() {
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String text = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                switch (text){
                    case "Prova1":
                        setFragment(fragmentProva1);
                        break;
                    case "Prova2":
                        break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void setFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentTop_id, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

fragment_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".FragmentTop">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/fragmentTop_id" />

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

FragmentProva1.java

```
public class FragmentProva1 extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private TextInputLayout textInputSideA;
    private TextInputLayout textInputSideB;
    private TextInputLayout textInputSideC;
    private TextView result;
    private Button btnCalculate;
    private LinearLayout Prova1LinearLayout;

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FragmentProva1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static FragmentProva1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentProva1 fragment = new FragmentProva1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_prova1, container, false);

        textInputSideA = view.findViewById(R.id.textInputSideA);
        textInputSideB = view.findViewById(R.id.textInputSideB);
        textInputSideC = view.findViewById(R.id.textInputSideC);
        result = view.findViewById(R.id.result);
        Prova1LinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.Prova1LinearLayout);

        btnCalculate = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
        btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                double info1;
                double info2;
                double info3;

                if(!validateLatoA() | !validateLatoB() | !validateLatoC()){
                    return;
                }
                info1 = calculate();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    private boolean validateLatoA(){
        String latoA_Input = textInputSideA.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

        if(latoA_Input.isEmpty()){
            textInputSideA.setError("Field can't be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            textInputSideA.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validateLatoB(){
        String latoB_Input = textInputSideB.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

        if(latoB_Input.isEmpty()){
            textInputSideB.setError("Field can't be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            textInputSideB.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validateLatoC(){
        String latoC_Input = textInputSideC.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

        if(latoC_Input.isEmpty()){
            textInputSideC.setError("Field can't be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            textInputSideC.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_prova1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".FragmentProva1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent"
        android:padding="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/Prova1LinearLayout">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputSideA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="info1"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputSideB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="info2"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputSideC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="info3"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Calculate"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:id="@+id/btnCalculate"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:padding="16dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You have multiple choices. Listener, broadcast receiver or use some libs like EventBus. I would recommend broadcast receiver if you wanna learn android deeply or EventBus if you looking for an easy way.